# Using calculus to find inverse functions

Tags: calculus, functions

High schooler here. Last summer I taught myself a little bit of calculus, and I have been doodling about it. So I began writing some problems for myself, and one of them was this:

Find the inverse function of $f(x) = ax + b$.

I think it's easy to show that the answer is $\frac{1}{a}(x-b)$ using algebra tricks. But I'm going to try something else:

$$
y = ax + b \\
y + dy = a(x + dx) + b \\
dy = a \cdot dx \\
\frac{dy}{dx} = a
$$

So as $y$ is a function of $x$ with slope $\frac{dy}{dx}$, the inverse of it should be $x$, a function of $y$ with slope $\frac{dx}{dy}$. So the slope of the inverse function should be

$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{a}
$$

So I integrate both sides, and I use my knowledge that $f(0)=b$.

$$
f^{-1}(x) = \int \frac{1}{a} \, dx = \frac{1}{a}(x-b)
$$

So this technique works for this function. Now I want to find the inverse function of the following function:

$$
f(x) = x \cdot \sin x
$$

The algebraic methods I've learned at school does not work for this one. I use my own technique to obtain

$$
\frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{1}{\sin x + x \cdot \cos x}
$$

I write $f^{-1}=u$ here for notational sugar. Now I get,

$$
u' \cdot \sin u + u' \cdot u \cdot \cos u - 1 = 0
$$

This is clearly an equation involving functions and their derivatives, and I've been trying to solve the equation but couldn't find an answer. I've done some research and found Laplace transforms, learned the basics of it, but I still cannot find the transform of the second term in the last equation. I have a few questions about this:

1. Is my method valid?
2. Using this method, will the equations I obtain in the last step have only one function as a root?
3. If there are multiple functions that will satisfy the equation, will their graphs be identical?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are going to have to restrict your domain to find an inverse to $x \sin x$ as this is not 1-to-1

Comment: Interesting circle of ideas, however, we usually try hard to change problems of calculus into problems of algebra. You are doing the opposite. So, I don't have too much hope for your method as differential equations are a bit harder to solve than algebraic equations in many instances.

Comment: Maybe the frobenius method, substituting in a Fourier or power series and getting a recurrence relation, would work? The different branches are [graphed](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=y’+sin%28y%29%2By’+y+cos%28y%29-1%3D0) using the constant of integration to translate the inverse function